# Custom view disappears on opening, and then closing of keyboard (Android)

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-softkeyboard

I have a custom view, which is a line that 'grows' from a certain start point to a certain end point, at the bottom of the screen. When the soft key opens up, and I close it back, my custom growing line is no more on screen. What do I do to make my growing line not disappear on opening and then closing of keyboard.

I have tried using

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

But it doesn't work.

Also, I tried 'redrawing' the lines in the 'ónResume()' of my activity - but it doesn't work either.

Here are some screenshots:

[This image has small bright line at bottom started from the left most circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCgw5.png)

[This image has keyboard open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzEV9.png)

[This image is after closing the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi3oO.png)

As you can see, in the 3rd image, which is taken after closing the keyboard, the small bright line, that had started from left most circle has disappeared.

Comment: any screenshot?

Comment: @UsamaAltaf, added screenshots in question - please check.

Comment: your xml and java file

Comment: what logic are you using to fill the line? you must be doing some calculations,so I would try putting those calculations to on keyboard closed method, but the best solution is to really step through the custom view to see what it changes after keyboard is closed. @SparshDutta

Comment: Thanks Usama Altaf and Ajay P. Prajapati. I did  a kind of fix by listening to keyboard close event, and redrawing the lines on keyboard close.